# after upgrading to macOS Mojave, git isn't detecting changes

Tags: git, github, macos-mojave

So, firstly git wasn't even detected as being initialized in my repos. That was fixed running this command:

`xcode-select --install`

this got git back up and running, but now I'm having a more specific problem.

I have a git repo where I merged another repo into it. (basically a node & react project that were each in separate repos, but now combined into one).

it will detect changes made in the parent (node) project but not in the child repo. if I make small changes and check out the git status I get:

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Which is not true. Anyone have any experience with this and can tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Check your `.gitignore` and make sure the files you're editing are not included in that.

Comment: Are you sure that the other repo wasn't just added as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: @robertklepit was definitely added as a submodule.... I think.